# Tools or sites to configure Linux desktop hardware

Tags: linux, hardware-compatibility

I need to build a desktop Linux development system. I’m completely comfortable with configuring the software but I’d rather not spend days trying to figure out the right cords to configure the new system. Is there any site that can help select appropriate compatible case, motherboard, graphics, and so forth without requiring a week of research?

Comment: Rule of thumb: common stuff is supported, older stuff is supported, special hardware that only exists on that particular motherboard is not supported. You can't know in advance, because there's most of the time no detailed documentation about what's actually on your motherboard... the only way to know for sure is collect the PCI/USB/etc. IDs (if you can) and look at the kernel code. Which takes a week of research. Yes, it's a PITA. Or you just risk it; as long as you need it only for development, you don't need special hardware.

Comment: You can also choose models with Linux preinstalled. That's a pretty good indicator of overall acceptable support.